# PHP functions return null instead of boolean

Tags: php

In one of PHP questions on assessmentee.com, following code:

```
$a = "";
echo gettype($a);
echo empty($a);
echo is_null($a);
echo isset($x);
```

returns only "string1"

Why don't we have three bolean values returned, one for each of three functions: empty(), is_null() and isset()?

Comment: Have you tried to work this out yourself?

Comment: `echo` prints to string. `false`, `true`, `null` are not represented as strings, I can't find right now something to share with you explaining it, but you could also use `var_dump`.

Comment: yeah, I've tried to get why I'm not getting zeroes for false values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get all the results :string, true, false & false

```
echo gettype($a);  // outputs "string"
echo empty($a);    // outputs 1 (true)
echo is_null($a);  // outputs false, or "" in echo
echo isset($x);    // outputs false, or "" in echo
```

Your could try running it this way to see the different resuls:

```
echo gettype($a),'-',empty($a),'-',is_null($a),'-',isset($x),'-';
```

output: string-1---

Answer (score 5):

```
echo gettype($a);  // outputs "string"
echo empty($a);    // outputs true, in your environment this is 1
echo is_null($a);  // outputs false, "" isn't null, in your environment this is probably blank
echo isset($x);    // outputs false, in your environment this is probably blank
```

Comment: so, false wil echo as blank? why?

Comment: @Milos See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting

Answer (score 1):

```
echo gettype($a);  // Outputs a "string" because the datatype used is a string
echo empty($a);    // Outputs true, because the criteria that it is an empty string
echo is_null($a);  // Outputs false, "" isn't null, this is probably blank
echo isset($x);    // Outputs false because isset means "is set"
```